# Call an API from another API using Axios and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios

I'm using the following function to get data (results) from the pokemon api:

```
    const [data, setData] = useState({ results: []})


    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await api.get('/pokemon');
            setData(response.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

My API function:

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2'
});
```

And this is the response I have

```
 {
  "count": 964,
  "next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20",
  "previous": null,
  //data that I need to use
  "results": [
    {
      "name": "bulbasaur",
      "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
      //the get request in the URL above can work both with name or number in pokedex.
    },
    //the list goes on till the 20th pokemon.
  ]
```

How can I perform a get request from the url that's inside of the object in results array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the response and the details for each individual pokemon from you API you map over the `response.results` and use `Promise.all` to make a series of API calls and resolve it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await api.get('/pokemon');
    // if you want to get the details as well

    // details.data will be an array with details for all the pokemon that you get
    // from response
    const details = await Promise.all(response.data.results.map((el) => {
           return axios.get(`/pokemon/${el.name}`)

      }));
    };    

    fetchData();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await api.get('/pokemon');
    setData(response.data);

    const { url } = response.data.results[0];
    const reponse2 = axios.get(url);
    // do what you want with response2
};
```

alternatively, you may want to loop through the results

```
for(const result of response.data.results){
    const { url } = result;
    const reponse = axios.get(url);
    // do something with response
}
```